# Troubleshoot empty Cartopy streamplot

Tags: cartopy

I'm trying to plot streamlines of vector data using Cartopy (0.17.0), but the resulting figures are empty.  Using straight matplotlib (3.1.1) works.  The array and paths properties for the arrow PatchCollection and lines LineCollection are empty.

I've tried different projections, explicitly creating `x`, `y`, `v`, and `u` from `cartopy.vector_transform.vector_scalar_to_grid()`, removing/changing extents, removing nans from velocity fields.

Simple reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([233., 236.83146159, 240.66292318, 244.49438477])
y = np.array([28., 31.645003, 35.290006, 38.935009])
u = np.array(
      [[ 0.03955199, -0.22247993, -0.25873835,  0.04202399],
       [-0.23483805,  0.09814767, -0.10702853,  np.nan],
       [ 0.21835904,  0.06390616, np.nan,       np.nan],
       [ 0.19803461,  np.nan,     np.nan,       np.nan]]
)
v = np.array(
    [[-0.0986053 ,  0.05887021, -0.25543633, -0.20215461],
     [ 0.11536164, -0.11004942, -0.01419378, np.nan],
     [-0.06482275, -0.35679315, np.nan,      np.nan],
     [ 0.16507462, np.nan,      np.nan,      np.nan]]
)
ax = plt.subplot(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.streamplot(
    x, 
    y,
    u,
    v,
)
```

This works:

```
ax = plt.subplot()
plt.streamplot(
    x,
    y,
    u,
    v
)
```

Comment: This seems like a bug in CartoPy. I would open an issue at https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I found the following workaround:

```
    from cartopy.vector_transform import vector_scalar_to_grid
    from matplotlib.axes import Axes

    ax = plt.subplot(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    new_x, new_y, new_u, new_v, = vector_scalar_to_grid(
        ccrs.PlateCarree(),
        ccrs.PlateCarree(),
        5,
        x,
        y,
        u,
        v
    )

    Axes.streamplot(
        ax,
        new_x,
        new_y,
        new_u,
        new_v,
        transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()
    )
```